# Не передаётся картинка в скрипт с внешнего сервера через AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, изображения

Привет, проблема в теме. Пытаюсь загрузить картинку под номером 1 (в li c классом .first) со стороннего сервера. Выводится ошибка

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.lawofattraction.ru/_fr/9/6312821.gif. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Гугл говорит, это сделать нельзя, надо изменить в вызываемом скрипте заголовок. Это сделать, конечно, не могу

Код запроса - со строки 36 скрипта. Сам код: http://jsfiddle.net/FKE8P/1/

Comment: ajax'ом не загрузить со стороннего сайта, если они не сделали для вас заголовок `Allow-Origin`. 

А зачем вам ajax понадобился? Вы же знаете адрес картинки - так просто эту строку и дайте атрибуту `src=""` вашего тега `<img>`.

Comment: таково было задание.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой
Вот что пришло на ум: через ajax обращаетесь в свой php файл следующего примерного содержания:

```
<?php
$url="http://www.lawofattraction.ru/_fr/9/6312821.gif";
$data=file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;
```

Возможно ещё нужно добавить заголовки header("Content-type: image/gif") и, конечно, правильнее вместо file_get_countents использовать curl;

Comment: у меня нет php файла, только JS скрипт, который получает картинки. Есть какой-то другой способ так сделать. Типа альтернатива AJAX.

Comment: @olegall нет никакого другого способа, т.к. всё это противоречит same origin policy, вы не можете обратиться из js с правами пользователя браузера к данным к которым специально не разрешен доступ владельцем ресурса.  Вы можете их показать, но не считать данные. Интернет, в отличии от сектантов с  сайта, штука параноидальная. если вам нужен просто alert('success'); то вот http://jsfiddle.net/FKE8P/4/